# How to go down a list in different sheets with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have 3 sheets: Form66, Form65, and Matching. Both Forms have a column for ID starting at A9 and a column for Set starting at W9. I need to match these IDs if they share the same Set # in my Matching Sheet. The sample code I've included is written for my Matching sheet and it does this part fine.

What I'm missing is how to continue doing this for the range W9:W100 in form66, while continuing to populate my matching sheet whenever a value satisfies the `If` statement. How can I do that?

```
Dim row as integer

row = 3
If (Worksheets("Form66").Range("W9").Value = 1) Then    
    Cells(row, 1) = Worksheets("Form66").Range("A9").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a simple loop. Check out the code below

```
Sub foo()
Dim i As Long

Row = 3
For i = 9 To 100
    If Worksheets("Form66").Cells(i, "W").Value = 1 Then
        Cells(Row, i - 8) = Worksheets("Form66").Cells(i, "A").Value
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

You can also loop through worksheets if necessary:

```
For sht = 1 To Sheets.Count
    If Sheets(sht).Name = "Form66" Then
        'some code here
    End If
Next
```

Comment: A pure guess here, but should probably be `Cells(Row, i - 8) = Worksheets("Form66").Cells(i, "A").Value` to match.

Comment: Your guess is probably better than mine. I'm still not sure what is wanted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This seems like it should work, but instead of placing my IDs in Column A it is placing the three values which currently are =1 in A3, B3, and E3. I'm trying to tinker with it a bit to see if I can get to only fill in my A column, any suggestions?

Comment: I got it to work! Made a slight edit and now it runs perfectly! Thank you so much for your help!
`i = 9
row = 3

For i = 9 To 100
    If Worksheets("Form66").Cells(i, "W") = 1 Then
       'Cells(row, i - 8) = Worksheets("form66").Cells(i, "A").Value
    'MsgBox (Worksheets("Form66").Cells(i, "a"))
    Cells(row, 1) = Worksheets("form66").Range("a" & i).Value
    row = row + 1
    End If
Next `